# Incorrect request from jsp form

Tags: java, jsp

When I try submit my form tomcat throw me "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."
This is my jsp form. Please help me.

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="articleDTO" id="categoryForm">
    <form:errors path="*" />
    <td>Title</td>
    <td><form:input path="title" /></td>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <c:forEach items="${articleDTO.categories}" var="Category"
            varStatus="i" begin="0">
            <td><form:select path="categories[${i.index}]">
                    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                    <form:options items="${categoryList}" />
                </form:select></td>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="GG" /></td>
</form:form>
```

Conroller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAdminPage() {
    return new ModelAndView("admin_page").addObject("categoryList",
            categoryService.getAllCategories()).addObject("articleDTO", new ArticleDTO());
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView ondas(ArticleDTO articleDTO) {
    return new ModelAndView("done").addObject("article", articleDTO);
}
```

DTO:

```
private String title;

@NotEmpty
@Range(min = 100, max = 6000)
private String description;

@NotEmpty
private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

public ArticleDTO() {
    Category category = new Category();
    category.setTitle("news");
    category.setId(1L);
    Category category1 = new Category();
    category1.setTitle("news1");
    category1.setId(2L);
    categories.add(category1);
    categories.add(category);
}
```

I'm try to get from user list of article categories

Comment: Turn your logs to DEBUG. They will tell you what's wrong and you can post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure your POST is having validation issues... :)

Try to change your method to something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView ondas(ArticleDTO articleDTO, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("admin_page").addObject("categoryList",
        categoryService.getAllCategories()).addObject("articleDTO", new ArticleDTO());
    }
    return new ModelAndView("done").addObject("article", articleDTO);
}
```